# Searching for and copying Android app text elements running it on a PC

Tags: search, copy-paste, text-selection

Problem: some Android apps present large portions of text and/or large forms, which, unlike web pages, are not friendly to searching or copy-pasting. Consider a generated value (like ticket reservation id, but longer) that you can't search for (to verify) or select (to copy).

Can we somehow run this unfriendly app on a PC and have a browser-like (maybe even devtools-like) interaction with its whole layout, doing anything we want with the displayed text values? What simulator or VM could help?

Comment: Have you tried the commands mentioned here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26586685/is-there-a-way-to-get-current-activitys-layout-and-views-via-adb

Comment: For copy-pasting, a possible alternative is to take a screenshot and share it to a text recognition app (e.g. Google Lens).